# What are the differences between pre-built and user-provided hadoop on spark download page?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop

These questions have been puzzeling me for a long time：

There are five package types in the second selector when the first one is choosing version 2.4.4  .And I am confued about 3 of them: `Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7`,`Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop`,`Pre-built with scala 2.12 and user-provided Apache Hadoop`.Let me list my questions one by one.

1. What are the difference between `Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7` and `Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop`? Does this mean there are two different situation,I already have a hadoop cluster,and I don't have a hadoop cluster. If the former, I should choose `Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop`,and if the latter,this package will install a hadoop cluster for me ?
2. What are the difference between `Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop`and `Pre-built with scala 2.12 and user-provided Apache Hadoop`? As far as I know, spark have scala already installed when I run `spark-shell` following the tutorail,whose package seems not to be `Pre-built with scala 2.12 and user-provided Apache Hadoop` ,but just `Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop`.(Am I right?)  Because I think the command line shows someting using scala:

   > scala> val a = 1;

So why there is still another package emphasize that it is pre-built with scala 2.12?

Comment: There are multiple vendors of commercial Hadoop distributions. The top **six** are: Cloudera. Hortonworks. Amazon Web Services Elastic MapReduce Hadoop Distribution. Microsoft. MapR. IBM InfoSphere Insights.

Comment: @Elliott But Hortonworks and Cloudera are the same and Azure just uses their products. MapR doesn't exist anymore, and you've missed at least Qubole

Comment: @cricket_007 Certainly Cloudera recently acquired Hortonworks, the list came from google (top 6 hadoop vendors), and the point was the various builds exist to support the multitude(s) of vendors and solutions on the market.

Comment: @Elliott Maybe I missed something, but the question seems to be asking about downloading Spark, not Hadoop vendors?

Comment: @cricket_007 Sometimes you want to use an open source spark api, and you have a vendor supplied Hadoop... in which case, you want to download the pre-built version with user-provided Apache Hadoop where the version matches that provided by the vendor. Using the one pre-built for a different version of Hadoop isn't going to be compatible. That's how I decide which to download.

Answer (score 2):

Summary,

- we will need to install Hadoop separately in all three cases (1., 2., and 3.) if we want to support HDFS and YARN
- if we don't want to install Hadoop, we can use pre-built Spark with hadoop and run Spark in Standalone mode
- if we want to use any version of Hadoop with Spark, then 3. should be used with a separate installation of Hadoop

For Spark 3.1.1 the following package types exist for download:

1. Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 2.7

> This version of spark runs with Hadoop 2.7

2. Pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.2 and later

> This version of spark runs with Hadoop 3.2 and later

3. Pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop

> This version of spark runs with any user-provided version of Hadoop.

From the name of last version (spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz), it appears that we will need HADOOP for this spark version (i.e., 3.) and not the other versions (i.e., 1. and 2.). However, the naming is ambiguous. We will need Hadoop only if we want to support HDFS and YARN. In the Standalone mode, Spark can run in a truly distributed setting (or with daemons on a single machine) without Hadoop.

For 1. and 2., you can run Spark without a Hadoop installation as some of the core Hadoop libraries come bundled with the spark prebuilt binary, hence `spark-shell` would work without throwing any exceptions); for 3., spark will not work unless a HADOOP installation is provided (as 3. comes without the Hadoop runtime).

For more information, refer [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#preparations) from the docs

> There are two variants of Spark binary distributions you can download. One is pre-built with a certain version of Apache Hadoop; this Spark distribution contains built-in Hadoop runtime, so we call it with-hadoop Spark distribution. The other one is pre-built with user-provided Hadoop; since this Spark distribution doesn’t contain a built-in Hadoop runtime, it’s smaller, but users have to provide a Hadoop installation separately. We call this variant no-hadoop Spark distribution. For with-hadoop Spark distribution, since it contains a built-in Hadoop runtime already, by default, when a job is submitted to Hadoop Yarn cluster, to prevent jar conflict, it will not populate Yarn’s classpath into Spark ...

Hope this clears a bit of the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

No option will install Hadoop for you. In all cases, Hadoop must pre-exist or its bundled in the Spark download for you and you must first create a HDFS and YARN environment for Spark to run against if you want to run it that way

You can choose the user provided Hadoop if you already have a running cluster and want to add or upgrade Spark, or you're using Spark Standalone, on Mesos, or on Kubernetes instead, in which case Hadoop scripts are not included in the download, although Spark still relies on core Hadoop libraries internally to function

Spark also does not install Scala (or Java) for you. It's simply compiled against Scala 2.12 so trying to run against any other Scala version will result in classpath issues

Comment: Thank you! But I can run `spark-shell`  and enter a scala command line after unzipping the tarball ,and I can run scala code there.Isn't it  that Spark installed Scala for me?This is different from your answer.@cricket_007

Comment: No, Java and Scala must be pre-installed